# Keywork sslprotocols is not supported in .NET

Tags: .net, redis, tls1.2, stackexchange.redis

I am planning to update my minimum `TLS` version to `1.2` in the Azure portal.

So, I have updated `StackExchange.Redis` to 2.0 and added `sslprotocols=tls12` in the Redis connection string.

But all I am getting is an error `Keyword 'sslprotocols' is not supported`.

I have tried many things but nothing helped me

Comment: Exactly which library version of SE-Redis are you using, and are you using SE-Redis directly, or via some other intermediate library? sslProtocols is definitely the keyword
 (case shouldn't matter)

Comment: @MarcGravell, I am using SE-Redis V2.1.58. Actually, I am getting the error on GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseRedis(new RedisScaleoutConfiguration(connectionString, eventKey))

Comment: well, that API call isn't SE-Redis, so it is hard to advise. But to the best of my knowledge: 2.1.58 definitely includes that all logic.

Comment: It's my bad, Actually, the error is at SE.Redis.StrongName assembly. Thank you for the info @MarcGravell

Comment: ah, I wondered about that; yeah, that's the old old version; I've gone ahead and marked it deprecated in NuGet (linking to StackExchange.Redis instead)

Comment: Yeah. I am initializing the Redis connection string via Microsoft.Aspnet.SignalR.Redis library. It has the dependency of StrongName library. Anyhow I should have to use the SE.Redis.StrongName assembly, right?

Comment: that assembly *does not support* the ssl protocols configuration setting, and it isn't being updated, just so we're clear; but if that is what you need to use: good luck!

Comment: Actually, the StrongName library V1.2.6 supports sslprotocols configuration

Answer (score 1):

I know the answer is kind of discernable from the comments, but this is such an important question I thought I'd make sure the answer is clear for everyone:

- Install `StackExchange.Redis.StrongName` 1.2.6 to your project **even though it's deprecated** and even though it's already a dependency of `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Redis`
- You will need a `web.config` mapping like such:

  ```
    <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="StackExchange.Redis.StrongName" publicKeyToken="c219ff1ca8c2ce46" culture="neutral"/>
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.2.6.0" newVersion="1.2.6.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
  ```
- Setup the backplane like this:

  ```
        var connectionString = $"{server}:{port},password={password},ssl=True,sslprotocols=tls12,abortConnect=False";
        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseRedis(new RedisScaleoutConfiguration(connectionString, "hubName"));`
  ```

You will now be able to set the Minimum TLS Version of your Redis Cache in Azure to 1.2.